# unable to access mounted iso through terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Can anyone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

PS: here is a link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5wox3c1r1w2ylf/Screenshot%20from%202013-08-10%2017%3A11%3A14.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is case-sensitive AND whitespace sensitive - any of the following should work

```
cd Heroes\ III

cd "Heroes III"

cd 'Heroes III'
```

or you can just type enough of the name to be unambiguous (in this case just H would be enough since there's only one file, but for illustration let's add a few more characters)

```
cd Her
```

and then press the TAB key to let the shell auto-complete the filename with the necessary quotes / escapes for you